# Why can't Coq infer my coercion when applying arguments to coercible term?

Tags: coq

I'm trying to write a coercion of a specific sigma type into a binary relation. The coercion works when using a coercible term as a function argument, but not when using the same term as a function.

Here is the code:

```
Definition relation A := A -> A -> Prop.

Definition is_serial {A} (R: relation A) := forall x, exists y, R x y.

Definition serial state := {R: relation state | is_serial R}.

Definition serial_to_relation A (s: serial A) : relation A := proj1_sig s.
Coercion serial_to_relation : serial >-> relation.

Parameter foo: serial nat.
Parameter bar: relation nat -> Prop.

(* Succeeds in coercing an argument. *)
Check (bar foo).

(* Fails to coerce when applying arguments to coercible term *)
Fail Check (foo 1 2).
```

Here's an executable version of the snippet: https://x80.org/collacoq/udutosoher.coq

Why does the second check fail? Did I make a mistake in my coercion definition? Or is this some limitation of coercion inference that I'm unaware of?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem in the last case is that Coq tries to infer a function type for `foo` and `relation A` is not literally a function type (only up to unfolding of the definition of `relation`).

If you add a coercion to `Funclass` (see the [doc](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/addendum/implicit-coercions.html#classes)) as follows then the last test goes through

```
Definition serial_to_fun A (s: serial A) : A -> A -> Prop := proj1_sig s.
Coercion serial_to_fun : serial >-> Funclass.
```

Answer (score 0):

Well. It is just not able to "understand" that you want it to coerce to relation nat.

When you write `Check (bar foo).` coq should unify type which the `bar` is expecting (namely `relation nat`) and the type which `foo` has (namely `serial nat`). So, coq tryes to unify `serial nat` and `relation nat` and since these types are not convertable, coq "understands" that it needs try to use coercion. So, it tryes to find coercion from `serial nat` to `relation nat`. And since you have provided such a coercion, it succeeds.

*Edit*.
When you write `Check (foo 1 2).` coq will try to unify type of the `foo`  (namely `serial nat`) and type of function like `(nat -> nat -> A)` . So, again, it just does able not see that you want it to coerce `foo` to `relation nat`.